# Can Jetpack Compose be used with Kotlin 1.8.0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The release notes for Kotlin 1.8.0 mention Jetpack Compose
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html

But the latest version that can be used by Jetpack Compose is 1.7.21
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

What am I missing here?

Update: Literally hours after posting this, Jetpack released 1.4.0 which is compatible with Kotlin 1.8.0.

Comment: use compose compiler `1.4.0` - this is compatible with kotlin `1.8.0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **Kotlin 1.8.0** release notes mention that Jetpack Compose is now supported by the Kotlin language, but it does not necessarily mean that the current version of Jetpack Compose **1.4.0-alpha02** is compatible with Kotlin **1.8.0**.

The version of Jetpack Compose that is listed on the Android developer website **(1.7.21)** is the latest version that has been tested and is known to work with the specified version of the Kotlin language.

To use the latest version of **Kotlin (1.8.0)** with Jetpack Compose, you will need to wait for a new version of Jetpack Compose that is compatible with **Kotlin 1.8.0** to be released.

**Update**

Jetpack compose compiler version `1.4.0` is compatible with Kotlin `1.8.0` - release notes : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler#1.4.0

Comment: Thanks, I think you meant to say that the latest version of Jetpack Compose 1.4.0-alpha02 (at the time of writing this), not 1.7.21. 

It's not just a suggestion either, one of the Compose libraries throws an exception and crashes the app if the Kotlin version isn't supported.

Comment: yes, sorry ,will edit now

Comment: Currently the latest version of kotlin compiler is 1.4.0-alpha02 and it added support only for Kotlin 1.7.21

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Its just been updated to `1.4.0` -which is compatible with kotlin 1.8.0 according the commit history https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler#1.4.0

Comment: lol, talk about bad timing.  That must have been updated just hours ago.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Check your versions from here:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

A screenshot of the link is below.

[image]

For my case Compose Compiler Version 1.4.6 and Compatible Kotlin Version is 1.8.20. So I modify the kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion as 1.4.6 and org.jetbrains.kotlin.android as 1.8.20

and now modify your files as:

inside build.gradle (:app)

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.6'
}
```

Inside build.gradle (AppName)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.4.2'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}
```